# Check for two variables on view page but send one from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have one controller which checks if username is correct or not on user input and based on correct/not correct I send different variables to view page.

So what I have in controller is this

```
public function resSub() {

    $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        // not relevant stuffs
        $enc = 'enc';
        return View::make('users.page2', ['enc'=> $enc]);
    }
    Session::put('user_id', $user['user_id']);
    return Redirect::to('/users/page2?_token=' . csrf_token());
}   
public function encMess()
{
    $data = Session::all();    
    $enc1 = 'enc1';    
    return View::make('users.page2', ['enc1'=> $enc1]);
}
```

In the view I have this

```
@if(!$enc)
    <pre>{{ $enc1 }}</pre>
@else
    <pre>{{ $enc }}</pre>
@endif
```

When I run the page I get either `$enc` or `$enc1` not defined because it isn't sent to the view.

How can I make this?

Comment: Where's the `$enc` being defined? You're sending it to the view file, but it's not defined in your controller.

Comment: what's the difference between your two funciton all direct to same page?

Comment: Difference is the message which is send to the view and different function to perform to get this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function resSub() {

    $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        // not relevant stuffs
        return View::make('users.page2', ['enc'=> $enc]);
    }
    Session::put('user_id', $user['user_id']);
    return Redirect::to('/users/page2?_token=' . csrf_token()); }   

public function encMess() {
    $data = Session::all();        
    return View::make('users.page2', ['enc'=> $enc1]); 
}
```

View:

```
{{ $enc }}
```

You are doing the same thing in your view so you don't need to pass two different variable name.

If you really need to have two seperated variable use can pass one with an empty value.

Comment: Ahhh, of course. What you mean by: **You really need to have two seperated variable use can pass it with an empty value.**?

Comment: There was a "if" missing in the sentence, I changed it. Sorry for this.